# Compile PDF without proofs

Tags: conditionals, compiling

I am writing my degree thesis, and I need to make a synthesis of it: basically what I want to do is make a copy without the proofs...is there a way to exclude them automatically, without having to delete them manually?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`comment`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package and say, in the preamble,

```
\excludecomment{proof}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}

\excludecomment{proof}

\begin{document}

Text before the proof
\begin{proof}
Text for the proof
\end{proof}
Text after the proof

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the proofs again, simply comment out the `\excludecomment{proof}` line.

Comment: @Nico You're welcome. If you consider that my answer solved you problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Oh ok sorry! Marked it! Ehehe! Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, but beware that this will not work if you have nested proof environments.